# How do I get a function to return a Vec of string-like things?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I had a large block of code that opens files and searches the contents line by line, then does something to each matching line.  I want to factor this out into its own function that takes the path to a file and gives you the matching lines, but I cannot figure out how to correctly factor this out.

Here's what I think is close, but I get a compiler error:

```
/// get matching lines from a path
fn matching_lines(p: PathBuf, pattern: &Regex) ->  Vec<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    // TODO: maybe move this side effect out, hand it a
    //       stream of lines or otherwise opened file
    let mut f = File::open(&p).unwrap();
    match f.read_to_string(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(yay_read) => yay_read,
        Err(_) => 0,
    };
    let m_lines: Vec<String> = buffer.lines()
        .filter(|&x| pattern.is_match(x)).collect();
    return m_lines;
}
```

And the compiler error:

```
src/main.rs:109:43: 109:52 error: the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for the type `collections::vec::Vec<collections::string::String>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:109         .filter(|&x| pattern.is_match(x)).collect();
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:109:43: 109:52 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:109:43: 109:52 note: a collection of type `collections::vec::Vec<collections::string::String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str`
src/main.rs:109         .filter(|&x| pattern.is_match(x)).collect();
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

If I use `String` instead of `&str` I instead get this error:

```
src/main.rs:108:30: 108:36 error: `buffer` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:108     let m_lines: Vec<&str> = buffer.lines()
                                             ^~~~~~
```

Which kind of makes sense.  I guess the lines stay inside the `buffer` which goes out of scope at the end of the function, so collecting a vector of references to strings doesn't really help us.

How do I return a collection of lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with this version, which runs on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) (it's a good idea to make a [MCVE](/help/mcve) when asking a question):

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn matching_lines(p: PathBuf, pattern: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open(&p).unwrap();
    match f.read_to_string(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(yay_read) => yay_read,
        Err(_) => 0,
    };
    let m_lines: Vec<String> = buffer.lines()
        .filter(|&x| x.contains(pattern)).collect();
    return m_lines;
}

fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from("/etc/hosts");
    let lines = matching_lines(path, "local");    
}
```

Let's look at the signature for [`str::lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines):

```
fn lines(&self) -> Lines // with lifetime elision
fn lines<'a>(&'a self) -> Lines<'a> // without
```

I've shown what it looks like in the source first, and what you can mentally translate it to second. It will return an iterator of string slices that are backed by the `String` you've read. This is a nice thing, as it's very efficient as only one allocation needs to have been made. However, you cannot [return an owned value and a reference to that value at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). The easiest thing to do is convert each of the lines into an owned string, as [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32816128/155423) suggests:

```
let m_lines: Vec<String> =
    buffer
    .lines()
    .filter(|&x| x.contains(pattern))
    .map(ToOwned::to_owned)
    .collect();
```

That gets your code to compile, but it can still be made nicer. Your `match` statement can be replaced with [`unwrap_or`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or), but since you are ignoring the error case completely, you might as well just use `_`:

```
let _ = f.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
```

Note that this **really isn't** a good idea. Errors are important to report, and throwing away to error will bite you when you need it to be reported the most! It's probably safer to use [`unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) and let your program die when an error occurs.

Next, don't use explicit `return` statements and don't provide type annotations unless you need to. Since your function returns a `Vec<String>`, you can replace the last two lines with just:

```
buffer
    .lines()
    .filter(|&x| x.contains(pattern))
    .map(ToOwned::to_owned)
    .collect()
```

You also could be more open about the types you accept for `p`, to better match what `File::open` supports:

```
fn matching_lines<P>(p: P, pattern: &str) -> Vec<String>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
```

All together:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn matching_lines<P>(p: P, pattern: &str) -> Vec<String>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open(p).unwrap();
    let _ = f.read_to_string(&mut buffer);

    buffer
        .lines()
        .filter(|&x| x.contains(pattern))
        .map(ToOwned::to_owned)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from("/etc/hosts");
    let lines = matching_lines(path, "local");
    println!("{:?}", lines);
}
```

Comment: I really strongly prefer unwrap to let _, after silent errors I never thought could happen bit me when they did.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik absolutely! I was just cleaning up the code to be clearer that the error was being ignored. I'll tweak the text a bit to indicate it's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way I can just return a `Lines` instead of a `Vec<String>` ? I keep getting a `wrong number of lifetime parameters`

Comment: @Conrad.Dean not with the code as structured now. That's the [other question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). You could do something like that if you passed a reference to the String (via `&str`) to the method that returns the `Lines`.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert your string slices to owned `String` objects with the `map` function.

```
let m_lines: Vec<String> = buffer.lines()
        .filter(|&x| pattern.is_match(x))
        .map(|x| x.to_owned())
        .collect();
```

You should then be able to return `m_lines` from the function.